# button content and wait cursor problems

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-4.0

I have a WPF application with a page with some code as shown below

```
public partial class MyPage : Page
{
    public MyPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Wait;
        this.btnClose.Content = "Cancel";

        //  some long time consuming processing

        this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
        this.btnClose.Content = "Close";
    }
  }
```

I am doing two things here on the Close button click hander which are causing problems. Before long processing I change the button context text to Cancel. I also want to change cursor for whole page to wait. Once long processing is done I set the cursor state and button content back to where it was. However I am facing following two issues.

1. When application is doing long running operation, I don't get to see the button content as Cancel. It just keep showing me original content CLose.
2. The cursor changes to Arrow only on the button. However on rest of page,I still keep getting same arrow cursor.

Any ideas how can these issue be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code runs on the UI thread by default, so nothing else can be executed on the UI thread (such as re-rendering the UI) until the thread finishes executing.

There are many ways of releasing control of the UI thread before the code finishes executing, but I find the simplest is to use a `Task` from the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) which can be used to run code on a separate thread.

For example,

```
// this runs on the main UI thread
this.Cursor = Cursors.Wait;
this.btnClose.Content = "Cancel";

Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    // this code runs on a background thread

    // some long time consuming processing
})
.ContinueWith((e) =>
{
    // this code runs from the UI thread again
    this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
    this.btnClose.Content = "Close";
});
```

It should be noted that UI objects can only be modified on the UI thread, which is why I put the second UI update in the `.ContinueWith(...)` of the task. An alternative to this would be to use the [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) to ensure code gets executed on the UI thread. If you decide you need this instead and can't find an easy example via Google, let me know and I'll write one here.

Answer (score 1):

This has to be a duplicate some where

```
public class WaitCursor : IDisposable
{
    private Cursor _previousCursor;

    public WaitCursor()
    {
        _previousCursor = Mouse.OverrideCursor;

        Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;
    }

    #region IDisposable Members

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Mouse.OverrideCursor = _previousCursor;
    }

    #endregion
}

using (new WaitCursor())
{
     //  long blocking operation
}
```

Comment: But #1 is moot.  That is blocking operation and so there is no opportunity to cancel.